# Has anyone gotten access to App Inventor for Android yet

Tags: android, app-inventor

I signed for up this quite a few weeks back now but as of yet haven't heard anything.

Has anyone been granted access yet? 
[Found here](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
I got my mail from the App Inventor Team on Friday, Sep 3.

I also signed up quite a few weeks ago. I think this will be the same like every other Google "Beta" rollout, step by step giving more users access.

Answer (score 0):

I think the App Inventor team is getting faster at processing applications.

If it has been a while, check the web site http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/

Some folks did not get their email invite for whatever reason but AI still knew they were in.